# Python - Detect if list of values/strings are dates, times, datetime, or neither

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime

Given a list of values or strings, how can I detect whether these are either dates, date and times, or neither?

I have used the pandas api to infer data types but it doesn't work well with dates. See example:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_redshift_dtype(values):
    dtype = pd.api.types.infer_dtype(values)
    return dtype
```

This is the result that I'm looking for. Any suggestions on better methods?

```
# Should return "date"
values_1 = ['2018-10-01', '2018-02-14', '2017-08-01']

# Should return "date"
values_2 = ['2018-10-01 00:00:00', '2018-02-14 00:00:00', '2017-08-01 00:00:00']

# Should return "datetime"
values_3 = ['2018-10-01 02:13:00', '2018-02-14 11:45:00', '2017-08-01 00:00:00']

# Should return "None"
values_4 = ['123098', '213408', '801231']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to return values dependent on conditions you specify:

```
def return_date_type(s):
    s_dt = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce')
    if s_dt.isnull().any():
        return 'None'
    elif s_dt.normalize().equals(s_dt):
        return 'date'
    return 'datetime'

return_date_type(values_1)  # 'date'
return_date_type(values_2)  # 'date'
return_date_type(values_3)  # 'datetime'
return_date_type(values_4)  # 'None'
```

You should be aware that Pandas `datetime` series *always* include time. Internally, they are stored as integers, and if a time is not specified it will be set to `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that'll give you exactly what you asked for using `re`

```
import re

classify_dict = {
    'date': '^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}$',
    'date_again': '^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} 00:00:00$',
    'datetime': '^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}$',
}

def classify(mylist):
    key = 'None'
    for k, v in classify_dict.items():
        if all([bool(re.match(v, e)) for e in mylist]):
            key = k
            break
    if key == 'date_again':
        key = 'date'
    return key

classify(values_2)
>>> 'date'
```

The checking is done iteratively using `regex` and it tries to match all items of a list. Only if all items are matched will the key be returned. This works for all of your example lists you've given.

For now, the regex string does not check for numbers outside certain range, e.g (25:00:00) but that would be relatively straightforward to implement.